# How to check if ACL is protected

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I have a tool which outputs the Owner and ACL of folders for documentation purposes. I now want to add a flag that indicates if the Inheritance on the path is enabled or not.

So far i could only find a .net class that provides that functionality ([DirectorySecurity -> AreAccessRulesProtected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.directorysecurity(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1)).

How can i do this in native c++? For the other functionality i use GetSecurityInfo but as far as i see i can´t get that information from it.

Thanks

Comment: you need call [`GetSecurityDescriptorControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446647(v=vs.85).aspx) and in [`SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_CONTROL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379566(v=vs.85).aspx) check `SE_DACL_PROTECTED` for *DACL* and `SE_SACL_PROTECTED` for *SACL*

Comment: @RbMm thanks so much, i have been searching for the last hour... if you want to formulate it as answer i will be glad to accept

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to RbMm´s comment i have solved the problem. For future readers here is a code snippet (no error handling):

```
PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = NULL;
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(path.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL);
...
GetSecurityInfo(hFile, SE_FILE_OBJECT, OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION | DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &pSD);
...

SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_CONTROL sdc;
DWORD dwRev = 0;
iRC = GetSecurityDescriptorControl(pSD, &sdc, &dwRev);
if (iRC== 0) {} //error
    else {
    if ((sdc & SE_DACL_PROTECTED) == SE_DACL_PROTECTED) {
            daclProtected = true;
        }
}
```